# how to add JSON data to an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have json data as below.

```
[
    {"id":"2","imagePath":"image002.jpg","enDesc":"Nice Image 2"},
    {"id":"1","imagePath":"image001.jpg","enDesc":"Nice Image 1"}
]
```

I am assigning this to variable named `NSArray *news`.

Now I have three different array as below.

```
NSArray *idArray;
NSArray *pathArray;
NSArray *descArray;
```

I want to assign data of news to these arrays so that finally I should have as below.

```
NSArray *idArray = @["2","1"];
NSArray *pathArray = @["image002.jpg","image001.jpg"];
NSArray *descArray = @["Nice Image 2","Nice Image 1"];
```

Any idea how to get this done?

---

With the help of below answer this is what I did.

```
pathArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[news valueForKey:@"imagePath"]];
```

I don't wanted to use NSMutableArray for some reasons.

Comment: Frankly, it's generally not a good idea to split apart a JSON structure like that.  Far easier and less bug-prone to simply carry the original dictionaries forward and access them directly where the individual values are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JSONKit or TouchJSON to convert your JSON data to Dictionary.
Than you may do this :

```
NSArray *idArray = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id"]; // KVO
```

Comment: for example:  NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:response error:&error];

Comment: You don't need external libraries. Foundation has `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: This Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

then you can extract all the information that you need from there you have **NSArray** that contains **NSDictionary** , where you can go and use **objectForKey:** to get all the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

Load the json data into an NSDictionary, which you may call "news" . Then retrieve as

```
NSArray *idArray = [news valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
NSArray *pathArray = [news valueForKeyPath:@"imagePath"];
NSArray *descArray = [news valueForKeyPath:@"enDesc"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes all the above ans is correct I am just integrating all of them together to be easly use to you:

```
NSArray *serverResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; // I am assigning this json object to an array because as i show it is in array format.
```

now:

```
NSArray *idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *pathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *descArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *news in serverResponseArray) 
{
   [idArray addObject:[news valueForKey:@"id"]];
   [pathArray addObject:[news valueForKey:@"imagePath"]];
   [descArray addObject:[news valueForKey:@"enDesc"]];
}
```

Comment: Please mansion that why any one did down vote. So that I can improve myself in future.