# Preparing NSArray from NSdictionary to show in next VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

pretty simple question.

- How do i create two arrays from my NSDictionary full of Json data?
- How do i then use these in my next vc and set that to the value of my cell.label.text?

Here is my current code as follows:

GroupsHomeViewController.h

```
// Toggle View Button (on button click open next view controller and populate table view with group matching data)
- (IBAction)ShowModels:(id)sender {

    NSString *var1 = self.groupLabel.text.lowercaseString;
    NSString *var3 = [var1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; //how to remove spaces personal reference.

    NSString *var2 = self.groupLabel.text.lowercaseString;
    NSString *var4 = [var2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    // NSLog(@"%@", var3); used for testing remove upon completion.

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.com/%@/%@.json", var3, var4]] completionHandler:^(
                                                                                                                                                                                       NSData *data,
                                                                                                                                                                                       NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                                                                                                                       NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        //need to assign @amount to a nsarray somehow and then display in next vc.
        //need to also assign amake to an nsarray and send to next vc also.


        NSLog(@"%@", json);

    }];

    //Run the completed task.
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

ModelViewController.h

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Set number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Set number of rows.
    return 0; //change to count.
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = @amount //...need to find code for this...
    //cell.detailedLabel.text = @model



    // Set data for cell:

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    @end
```

I would just like to know how to create the NSArray out of my dictionary i already know how to set them to my cell.label.text. Thanks for your help.

JSON format:

```
    {
    amount = 2;
    make = V8;
}
```

Comment: if your JSOn contains only two objects, you can give each one to an array. What have you tried to store json objects into array ?

Comment: I am aware that I can assign them to an array the problem is I don't how do this? Please could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: you could try this: [array1 addObject:yourJSon[@"amount"]]

Comment: for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470876/how-to-add-json-data-to-an-nsarray

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you very much my friend.

Comment: Lee Sugden I posted my answer.Check it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Lee Sugden you can easily get the data from dictionary and you ca add the objects to array.

```
NSMutableArray *arrJsonAmount = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrJsonMake = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arrJsonAmount addObject:[json objectForKey:@"amount"]];
[arrJsonMake addObject:[json objectForKey:@"Make"]];
```

UITableView DataSource Methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
  return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     return [arrJsonAmount count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = arrJsonAmount[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailedLabel.text = arrJsonMake[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What if the arrays are different sizes?

Comment: I hope that getting data almost is there.So according to me arrays size are equal .

Comment: Well that's naive.  You should never trust data you receive, especially if it will crash your app, which this can.

Comment: Yeah I got it Droppy.Thank you.